# How to display the data in the tableview cell from the array of array in swift

Tags: ios

I have the values as:-

```
[[yes,no],[yes,no]]
```

i need to display in cellForRowAt indexPath in tableview .

my code:-

```
 var tableArray:Array<[String]> = []
```

fetching the data from JSON:-

```
 if  let data = wholedata["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{
     print(data)
     print(response)
     for question in data {
         let options = question["options"] as! [String]
         self.tableArray.append(options)
         //  self.fetchedHome.append(options as! [home])
         self.no = options.count
     }
     print(self.tableArray)
```

my cell for row at index in tableview :-

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell
        }            
        print(reviewViewModel.tableArray)
        cell.question.text = "hai"

        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
}
```

How to display the data in the tableview cell?

Comment: how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't register the cell in `cellForRow`, register it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
private let identifier = "Cell" // Declare the identifier as private constant on the top level of the class.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    // do other stuff 
}
```

Then in `cellForRow` get the item for index path from the data source array. As the options are an array you have to display it in two labels or join the items.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as! QuestionListCell
    let options = tableArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.question.text = options.joined(separator: ", ")
    return cell
}
```

I guess you want to display more data than the `options`. But at the moment you are populating the data source array only with the `options`

Once again as suggested in my answer to one of your previous questions I highly recommend to decode the JSON into custom structs. It makes life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy question bro.

If you don't mind using section then try this~!!!

```
var tableArray:Array<[String]> = []

func viewDidLoad() {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.register(YourNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: YourIdentifier)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableArray[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let tempArray = tableArra[indexPath.section] as? [String],
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YourIdentifier) as? QuestionListCell {
        // just Initialize your cell with data in datasource
        cell.question.text = tempArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: here what should the YourCustomCell(withData:

Comment: you have to create your custom cell subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: please check i have updated my cellforrow at index.In that how to do?

Comment: I changed my answer please check it out . 
I don't think my code would perfectly match your goal but i hope it will help you~

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `array of array` into `array` before displaying in table and your tableViewController will only have the `array` of data.

You can use **flatmap/compactMap** to convert `array of array` to `array`:

```
let a = ["yes","no"]
let b = [a, a]      // [["yes","no"], ["yes","no"]]
b.flatMap({$0})     // ["yes","no", "yes","no"]
```